# hyperref form fields with umlauts

Tags: hyperref, luatex, unicode

I tried to create a PDF form using hyperref and prefill the form. But I had troubles with values that contain umlauts.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
    \TextField[name=test,value={Vögel},width=8cm]{Test}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

And I get this:

[image: result]

I'm using lualatex for creating the pdf.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `hyperref` option `unicode`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
    \TextField[name=test,value={Vögel},width=8cm]{Test}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

or option `pdfencoding=auto`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
    \TextField[name=test,value={Vögel},width=8cm]{Test}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

both result in:

[image: Vögel]